# archive.php looks different from template

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm wondering how Wordpress Templates work.

I have WooCommerce installed, and would like to have a page where its loading the product listing, but it seem to be defaulting to using the template file : archive.php. *archive.php* looks fine, all except the fact that the company logo and navigation bar on the top is missing. I've checked *archive.php* template file and it seem that the code for the logo is still there. I'm wondering which page the template is defaulting to other than archive.php.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce does not use the normal WP `archive.php` template. In order to customize the WooCommerce archive template you need to:

1. Make a new folder inside your theme directory called `woocommerce`.
2. Add this file to the `woocommerce` folder: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/master/templates/archive-product.php

You can then customize that new `archive-products.php` file to meet your needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, Mike, thanks for your help! I indeed tried to copy archive-products.php. Wordpress defaulted to archive-products.php. However, my navigation bar and logo is still missing. Is there a script somewhere that causes the navigation bar to go missing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... The `archive-products.php` file I linked to in my answer should pull in the "shop" header from your theme. Do you have a `header-shop.php` file in your theme folder? If so you should customize that, otherwise it should default to your normal `header.php` file in your theme folder... Not sure what you mean by a "script" that hides the nav bar... Can you confirm your nav bar code you want shown is inside either your `header.php` file or your `header-shop.php` file in your theme?